# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to retrieve the next `select` box items based on the previous `select` box `selected` item through ajax `jquery` in laravel .

**Example**

when I `select` a `car` making company,from `select` box I want to retrieve the `models` of that specific `maker` company in the next `select` box.

For that I have the following code

```
<select id = 'posts'>
   <option>Select Make</option>

      @foreach($posts as $post)
        <option value = "{{$post->id}}">{{$post->name}}</option>
      @endforeach




</select>
```

Following code will run when I change the `select` box

`Index.blade.php`

```
   <script type = 'text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#posts').on('change',function(){

                var postId = $(this).val();
                if(postId){
                   console.log(postId);
                   $.ajax({
                       type:'POST',
                       url:'/getModels/'+postId,

                       data:{'_token': token},
                       dataType:'json',
                       success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                 });
             }
          });
       });

</script>
```

I have `route`

```
Route::get('/getModels/{id}',[
'uses' =>   'MakeController@modelNames'

]);
```

`Controller`

```
public function modelNames($id){

        $newmodels = ModelType::where('makeid',$id);
        return view('Index',compact('newmodels'));
    }
```

**Problem**

The `data` is showing in console (check `.on('change')` I write console there) but the control is not coming `.ajax()`.And when I change the `select` box it shows me the following error in `console`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

This typeError is in `jsBootstrapValidation.js` file

What is wrong with this,please help !

Thanks

Comment: That is wrapped actually, I just type the code here, that's why, my fault, but in original code, that is wrapped in {{}}

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with laravel, but your html code not 100% valid. It will generate something like this

```
<select id = 'posts'>
   <option>Select Make
        <option value = "1">name1</option>
        <option value = "2">name2</option>
  </option>
</select>
```

What you need is

```
<select id = 'posts'>
   <option>Select Make</option>
   <option value = "1">name1</option>
   <option value = "2">name2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it is inside loop, the each time I will have `select make` !

Comment: i just closed the first option `outside` the `loop`, still that is not working

Comment: check now, is that okay ? @DanDuh, but still I'm having the same problem